# how can i use c++11 style callbacks in c# with swig

Tags: c#, c++, callback, swig

I'm having the following c++ callback code:

```
std::function<void(unsigned int channel, int value)> onCounterChange;
```

What do i need to add to my .i file to use this in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following delegate to use:

```
delegate void OnCounterChange(int channel, int value);
```

and this would be the callback:

```
OnCounterChange onCounterChange;
```